# How to allow some specific IP address to access my WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I have one WCF Service returns xml. I want only one IP address to access it for eg: 10.0.0.5

can some one tell me how can i do this. Please tell me other than Firewall and IIS

Comment: You should be able to check the IP in the request header.  This isn't 100% foolproof, as it can be spoofed, however.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ip filtering, something like next - https://stackoverflow.com/a/803813/182344

Or use [ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccessCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.checkaccesscore.aspx) where you get client IP from OperationContext.