# How to call many wcf services using a single wcf service?

Tags: c#, wcf

How to call many `wcf` services using a single wcf service ? I want to give access to only limited IP addresses. What method can be used to implement my requirement ?

Comment: what do you mean by "**to call many wcf services using a single wcf service**". About filtering by ip, you check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947349/how-to-allow-some-specific-ip-address-to-access-my-wcf-service

Comment: Thanks a lot , that helped