# Preventing certain applications to access endpoints in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soap-client

We have an application distributed across various client computers, which we don't want them to be accessing the server endpoints anymore. They are using WCF SOAP protocol. We don't want to change our endpoints since they will hurt other applications that we still want to work. Also, I cannot change the source code of the application we want to block since God knows how many people are using it and finding them and deploying it on those machines will be painful. It seems like I am asking for impossibility but perhaps someone has experienced a similar problem and found a workaround. I was thinking that perhaps there is a unique data in the message that is coming from that specific application that we can check and block accordingly. For instance, I have enabled the tracing in WCF and this is a activity XML log that I am reading:

[image]

As you see, there is a `<Execution ProcessName/>` element. It stores the name of the process (in this case an .exe file). However, from what I am reading, it belongs to the trace element, and not really being pushed to the server. If there is something like that in the message, then I can read it on the server side and block any requests coming from that process. As far as I am seeing from the Envelope, we are not sending any custom data that identifies the client process.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you have multiple applications that use the same service, and you want only one of them to stop working? And you can't modify any of them at all?

Comment: How about restrict based on IP address: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947349/how-to-allow-some-specific-ip-address-to-access-my-wcf-service

Comment: @JohnWu I can modify the server except for its endpoints.

Comment: @Thuan I cannot, because it will also block other applications on those computers as well, where our actual product is installed.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the `.config` file for the applications that you want to keep?