# Enable or disable certain IPs from accessing my WCF service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm looking for a way to enable or disable certain IPs from accessing and adding my WCF service as service reference.

Currently it's possible to add our Webservice publicly, how can I add an IP filter?
Or is there any other setting I could use?

I've seen [Can I setup an IP filter for a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722008/can-i-setup-an-ip-filter-for-a-wcf-service) about adding `<IPFilter />` to **web.config**, but the essential part in code is missing thus unusable.

Note; The webservices are part of a bigger project and cannot be separated as individual project which is available via HTTPS (a website).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The best way really should be by hardware firewalls - not your software application!

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't think there is an automatic way to do it in WCF, you have two main options:

1. If you want something secured, don't want to implement anything but your environment uses firewalls, you can configure the firewall in order to refuse the connections coming from specific IP addresses.
2. Otherwise, you can implement an IP filter as in the article you mentionned (i.e. as a serviceBeharvior, not described here) or simpler as a single private method called by all your public webservice methods that throw an error code if the IP of the client is not allowed (based on white or black lists of IPs in a file or a database).

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Get the client IP address.
   /// </summary>
   private string GetClientIpAddress()
   {
       string result = string.Empty;
       try
       {
           OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
           MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
           RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpointProperty = messageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
           result = endpointProperty.Address;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           logger.Error(ex);
       }

       return result;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Returns <code>true</code> if the current IP address is allowed
   /// to access the webservice method, <code>false</code> otherwise.
   /// </summary>
   private bool CheckIPAccessRestriction()
   {
       bool result = false;
       List<string> allowed = GetAllowedIpAddressesList();
       if (allowed.Count() == 0)
       {
           result = true;
       }
       else
       {
           var ip = GetClientIpAddress();
           result = allowed.Contains(ip);
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you Web service is hosted in IIS you can restrict IP addresses there:

[image]

Comment: Note; The webservices are part of a bigger project and cannot be separated as individual project. --The bigger project is available to everybody.

Comment: OK. So are you restricting access to the whole service? or just operations on a service? are there multiple services? Do you have control of the deployment of the service to the web server?

Comment: The WCF service is part of a web site project in webforms. I cannot separate the WCF service from the project as that would mean a rewrite of thousands and thousands lines of code. Yes, I could access the IIS if that's your question.

Comment: ok. You don't need to separate the WCF service from the project in order to implement the IP restrictions. What i'm trying to understand is 'how' you want the restrictions to work. Do you want to restrict access to everyone or a group of people? to the entire service or only one part of the service?

Comment: I don't want anyone have the ability to add the service reference to any project or call the service over http(s) via the browser. As long I can see the WSDL and meta info via the browser  AND add the project to visual studio I'm not satisfied

Comment: ok. The easiest way is to change the IP address restrictions for the  deployed service in IIS if you have access to it. The image above shows you where to add your own IP address. Any other IP addresses wont be able to see the WSDL or meta info. If you don't have access to IIS one alternative is to write a WiX installer to do it for you. That help ?

Comment: You said "The WCF service is part of a web site project in webforms". The answer is to ensure that the service is deployed to IIS in a separate folder to the web site project. If it's in a separate folder you can apply the restrictions as above without affecting any ones access to the web site.

Comment: Does localhost needs to be included? I'm going to block everything except localhost and my ip

Comment: It depends what accesses it and where it is. If it's hosted on your web server then it will definitely need your IP address. If your web site needs to talk to the web service then the service will also need to allow the loop back address 127.0.0.1 (which is localhost). If this is hosted on your machine then you don't need to add the loop back address.