# Wcf Cloud Service verify the Caller Identity without Login Information

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, azure-cloud-services

I'm doing my school project and in my case, I have a client and 2 WCF cloud service in Azure cloud and the first service then needs to call another service. The client (caller) need to call the WCF service and verify the caller identity without Login, and what way can I use in this case, My idea is to use SSL Authentication or IP to verify the caller identity and is this method is correct or any suggestion method to this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options for authentication. As you indicated you can use a [SSL certificate to validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication) that the client is who you think they are (preferably SHA2 or above).

You can also [white list by IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722008/can-i-setup-an-ip-filter-for-a-wcf-service/803813#803813) as you also mentioned. This could cause problems later if the there are multiple clients or their IP changes.

With WCF you can also use a [Custom User Name and Password Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator) where the client passes a user name and password in the request.

I think unless you have the option to use windows auth, tokens would be the other option, that is more complicated though. Using SSL or User Name Validator are probably the easiest to set up.